# SQL Server 2005 query (num rows and load interval)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am making project where I load huge database in my software,so I must load database by blocks.

I have 2 questions about that.

1. How do I select just some rows from table? For example:

   ```
   select * from table (row 10 to row 20)
   ```

   or it can be

   ```
   select * from table (row 10 and next 10 rows)
   ```
2. How do I get number of rows in table?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: " I load huge database " : how many rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1
```

for the first 10 records

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Customers
```

for the first 10 records.

To get number of rows in a table use:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

Comment: Also: using `TOP` *without* an `ORDER BY` in SQL Server makes no sense - you'll just get back 10 arbitrary rows. You should **always** provide an `ORDER BY` when using `TOP` to define **which ordering** is in place to return the "top 10" rows ...